# How to set global warning level in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am currently working with WebStorm and the ESLint configuration from Airbnb.

Is there a way to mark the errors from ESLint in a "softer" way instead of this "aggressive" red or mark all rules in ESLint as warning without listing every rule in the `.eslintrc` file with "warn"?

Comment: Try changing severity for ESLint in IDE settings (ESLint integration (showing errors/warnings) is done as separate Inspection ... and each inspection can have their Severity overridden to a lower/higher one).

Comment: unfortunately 'custom' severity highlighting doesn't currently work for eslint - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25697

Answer (score 1):

There is way to do that.

For instance if you save your config file as `.eslintrc.js` then you can create a global var, which you then pass to the rules. And you can change that for different files. Something like:

```js
export const severity = "error"
```

Comment: Here is a complete example: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10438#issuecomment-422465222